Showing reflections are isometries
I have a definition of a complex reflection. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$. A reflection is an element $r$ of $\text{GL}(V)$ that has finite order and such that $\ker(r-1)$ is a hyperplane in $V$.
I am trying to show that $r$ is an isometry, and I feel it should be easy but my brain isn't working.
I just need to show that if $r$ is a reflection then $(rv,rw)=(v,w)$ for all $v,w \in V$. I think this should be possible very directly from the definitions.

The way you defined it, it does not have to be an isometry (examples are easy to construct). Why do you think it is?

Oh really? It seems like reflections should be isometries as they are in the sense of Euclidean space
